# Apache Beam - ReadFromText safely (pass over errors)

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simple Apache Beam pipeline which reads compressed bz2 files and writes them out to text files.

```
import apache_beam as beam

p1 = beam.Pipeline()

(p1
        | 'read' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('bad_file.bz2')
        | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('file_out.txt')
 )

p1.run()
```

The problem is when the pipeline encounters a bad file ([example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8mii8jsm1jmqgi/bad_file.bz2?dl=0)). In this case, most of my bad files are malformed, not in bz2 format or simply empty, which confuses the decompressor, causing an `OSError: Invalid data stream`.

How can I tell ReadFromText to `pass` on these?

Comment: Hi @John F, did the answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, no it didn't, I'm still getting an error

Comment: Isn't "exception handling" what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54426096/9350720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to filter your files and then use [apache_beam.io.textio.ReadAllFromText](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.textio.html).

For example

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import fileio
from apache_beam.io import filesystem
from apache_beam.io import filesystems
import bz2


def is_valid_bz2(path):
    try:
        with filesystems.open(path, filesystem.CompressionTypes.BZ2) as handle:
            handle.peek()
            return True
    except Exception:
        return False


with beam.Pipeline() as p:

    (p
     | 'match' >> fileio.MatchFiles("/path/to/*.bz2")
     | 'filter' >> beam.Filter(lambda m: is_valid_bz2(m.path))
     | 'read' >> beam.io.textio.ReadAllFromText()
     | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('file_out.txt'))
```

Here `is_valid_bz2` yses the [filesystems](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.12.0/apache_beam.io.filesystems.html) utilities to be able to read from all supported filesystems.